# how to rewind proc file

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I am trying to read proc file /proc/stat at regular interval(200ms), and I am trying to avoid opening and closing the proc file every time.

Now since proc files don't have a size associated with it, fseek and rewind won't work. Please correct me if I am wrong. (I recall some proc files do have a size associated with them but /proc/stat definitely doesn't have one )

What's the proper way to reset the read pointer for proc file to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found `rewind` works just fine

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    FILE* fin = fopen("/proc/stat", "r");
    if (!fin) {
        perror("fopen");
        return -1;
        }
    char buf[16*1024];
    while(1) {
        rewind(fin);
        size_t sz = fread(buf, 1, sizeof(buf), fin);
        if (sz) {
            buf[sz]=0;
            printf(buf);
            }
        sleep(5);
        }
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: this looks ok, except there is no exit strategy and the criteria was every .2 seconds, not every 5 seconds, so using something like usleep or nanosleep would be a much better choice for the delay function in the loop.  And this means the the function would be restored to the 'exec' queue after 5 seconds (or the desired .2seconds, so either change the nice value to realtime (still not perfect timing) or check the elapsed time against the system clock and adjust the delay time to compensate for the timing drift.

Comment: OP was asking about how to re-read `/proc/stat` so the answer focused on that. It's assumed he can handle modifying the time/sleep parameters.